# Sort JavaScript structure

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this structure:

```
var example=[0,{ "3":4 , "6":1 , "11":2 }];
```

I would like to transform this into

```
[0,{ "6":1 , "11":2 , "3":4 }]
```

based on the number on the right (ascendant): `4, 1, 2` becomes `1 ,2, 4`.

Comment: You can't, objects are not sortable.

Comment: Technically you can't, but it seems like most browser implementations will iterate them in the order in which they were added to the object.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You can't trust on that, ["The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified"](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4).

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I said "technically you can't, but practically you pretty much can".

Comment: If you want things in a particular order, use an array, not a plain object to store them.  It's way, way, way easier to order things in an array.  While it can technically be done with a plain object in a modern browser, it's a major hassle and very prone to mistakes and hard to reorder things without creating an entirely new object.

Answer (score 0):

Infact order in objects are not guaranteed in JavaScript, you need to use an Array to have similar result:

```
function sortObjectByValue(obj) {
    var result = [];
    var key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr.push({
                'key': key,
                'value': obj[key]
            });
         }
    }
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    });
    return result; // returns array
}

>>>var obj = { "3":4 , "6":1 , "11":2 };
>>>console.log(sortObjectByValue(obj))
//[Object { key="6",  value=1}, Object { key="11",  value=2}, Object { key="3",  value=4}]
```

I will suggest also if you find your self dealing a lot with data-structure and need advanced methods check [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)